# How to use SubscriptionClient.OnMessage for a subscription that requires a session

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I've been looking at the new message pump available with version 2.0 of the azure service bus.  In particular, I'm using topics and subscriptions (and not the queues).

I can get the message pump to work with a non-session subscription and it raises the Message event whenever a brokeredMessage is available.  However, when I try to use a subscription that requires a session, I get the following error...

InvalidOperationException: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver

Does anyone have a way to use the new OnMessage event with a subscription that requires a session?

Comment: So, do you set the RequiredSession as true or false when you're creating your subscriptions?

Comment: I set RequiredSession = true when creating the subscription

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135960/azure-subscriptionclient-onmessage-and-sessions/36137001?noredirect=1#comment59920248_36137001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not yet available, we are working on adding support for `OnMessage` API on the `MessageSession` class and that will show up in a future SDK release. We will however add OnMessage support to the `MessageReciever` class in this SDK update.

Comment: Wanted to ask when this will be available, but just discovered that it's released in the Azure 2.3 SDK that just came out.