# Azure, SubscriptionClient.OnMessage, and Sessions

Tags: session, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

Does the Azure Service Bus Subscription client support the ability to use OnMessage Action when the subscription requires a session?

I have a subscription, called "TestSubscription". It requires a sessionId and contains multipart data that is tied together by a SessionId.

```
if (!namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists("TestTopic", "Export"))
{
    var testRule = new RuleDescription
    {
        Filter = new SqlFilter(@"(Action='Export')"),
        Name = "Export"
    };

var subDesc = new SubscriptionDescription("DataCollectionTopic", "Export")
{
    RequiresSession = true
};
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(sub`enter code here`Desc, testRule);
}
```

In a seperate project, I have a Service Bus Monitor and WorkerRole, and in the Worker Role, I have a SubscriptionClient, called "testSubscriptionClient":

```
testSubscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, _topicName, CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("testSubscription"), ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
```

I would then like to have OnMessage triggered when new items are placed in the service bus queue:

```
testSubscriptionClient.OnMessage(PersistData);
```

However I get the following message when I run the code:

**InvalidOperationException: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver**

I am using Azure SDK v2.8.

Is what I am looking to do possible? Are there specific settings that I need to make in my service bus monitor, subscription client, or elsewhere that would let me retrieve messages from the subscription in this manner. As a side note, this approach works perfectly in other cases that I have in which I am not using sessioned data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
var messageSession=testSubscriptionClient.AcceptMessageSession();

messageSession.OnMessage(PersistData);
```

beside of this:

```
testSubscriptionClient.OnMessage(PersistData);
```

**Edit:**
Also, you can register your handler to handle sessions (`RegisterSessionHandler`). It will fire your handle every new action.

I think this is more suitable for your problem.

He shows both way, in this [article](http://spikesoftware.azurewebsites.net/?p=2641). It's for queue, but I think you can apply this to topic also.

Comment: That works for one message on startup; meaning that AcceptMessageSession will get the next session from the service bus subscription and perform as intended. But if there are other sessioned messages in the service bus, they are not retrieved.  Should this call be placed in the Run() method?

Comment: I think after you get messages you should call AcceptMessageSession again. Check here http://www.jayway.com/2014/08/28/routing-commands-using-azure-service-bus-sessions/ this is for async.

Comment: That makes sense. Except that I don't know when messages will be entered into the service bus. So I need my service bus monitor to be able to detect new messages and trigger an event when new messages are discovered. It seems like the solution in the link, or even just calling AcceptMessageSession relies on me knowing that there are new sessions waiting, and having some "trigger" to call said code.

Comment: @KamauMalone I have edited answer. I think `RegisterSessionHandler` is more suitable for your solution.

Comment: That was exactly it - RegisterSessionHandler did the trick. Thanks much for your help in this Erkan!